# OpenTSDB no JDK found

Tags: java, debian, opentsdb

I'm having troubles starting OpenTSDB because no JDK is found allthough I've installed it and set JAVA_HOME. Here's what I've done:

**1. Install JDK**

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

**2. Set JAVA_HOME**

I tried setting JAVA_HOME in 2 different ways:

1. Add `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"` to `/etc/environment`
2. Add `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"` to `.bashrc`

**3. Download OpenTSDB**

```
wget https://github.com/OpenTSDB/opentsdb/releases/download/v2.3.0/opentsdb-2.3.0_all.deb
```

**4. Install OpenTSDB**

```
dpkg -i opentsdb-2.3.0_all.deb
```

**5. Start OpenTSDB**

```
service opentsdb start
```

Each time I get the error "* no JDK found - please set JAVA_HOME". I've tried numerous times, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is also present in `opentsdb 2.3.1`. To fix this issue you should explicitly write your `JAVA_HOME` to the opentsdb init script (at `/etc/init.d/opentsdb`)

open the file `/etc/init.d/opentsdb` and add the path to your java installation

here is the fix:

```
JDK_DIRS=" Path_to_your_JDK_here  \
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk \
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/ \
        \
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk \
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/ /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/ \
        \
  /usr/lib/jvm/default-java"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you try with these command after install jdk?

## update-alternatives --display java

## update-alternatives --config java

with this command select default JDK for the system.

Regards!